# Switch/Case not working as expected - null occurs as more than one when branch for this switch statement

Tags: apex, switch-case

I would except the following code to work but I get the following error:

> null occurs as more than one when branch for this switch statement

Any thought why?

BTW, if I add the value in the `when` as a string literal it works.

Found the [same issue](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2Fmichida%2Fitems%2F9c415264088622617512) somewhere else.

```csharp
private static String A = 'a';
private static final String B = 'b';
private final String C = 'c';

switch on obj.field__c {  
    when 'A'{ //This works
        callClassA();
    }
    when B{
        callClass(B);
    }
    when C{
        callClassC();
    }
    when else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can only use explicit string literals (no variables) in `when` blocks here. Note the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) explicitly states a literal value must be used:

> #### When Blocks
>
> Each when block has a value that the expression is matched against. These values can take one of the following forms.
>
> - `when literal {}` (a when block can have multiple, comma-separated literal clauses)
> - `when SObjectType identifier {}`
> - `when enum_value {}`
>
> The value `null` is a legal value for all types.
>
> Each when value must be unique. For example, you can use the literal x only in one when block clause. A when block is matched one time at most.