# How to switch on RecordTypeId inside a loop?

Tags: apex, record-type, loop, apex-variable

Alternative Title : How to optimize grouping each SObject records by Recordtypes

```
public static Id sgRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Singapore').getRecordTypeId();
public static Id myRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Malaysia').getRecordTypeId();

for(Account accObj : newAccountList) {
     SWITCH on accObj.RecordTypeId {
        when sgRecordTypeId {
            sgAccountIdSet.add(accObj.Id);
        }
        when myRecordTypeId {
            myAccountIdSet.add(accObj.Id);
        }
...
}
```

When I do the above code I get this error : `Id is not a valid switch expression type`

So I tried changing it to `SWITCH on String.valueOf(accObj.RecordTypeId) {` as mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/262841/38191) but get these errors:

```
1. null occurs as more than one when branch for this switch statement
2. Field must be an enum reference
```

Realised the error is because [You can only use explicit string literals (no variables)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/334205/38191)

But got stuck here ...

Note : Don't want to use if/else statement because it will make the Apex PMD complain about the cyclomatic complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch statements can only work on static (compile-time) values, not any computed value. As such, you might want to work with record type names instead:

```
Map<Id, RecordType> recordTypes = new Map<Id, RecordType>([
  SELECT Name FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Account'
]);
for(Account accRecord: newAccountList) {
  switch on recordTypes.get(accRecord.RecordTypeId)?.Name {
    when 'Singapore' {
      ...
    }
    when 'Malaysia' {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

For your specific use case, you can also use a Map by way of references:

```
public static Id sgRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Singapore').getRecordTypeId();
public static Id myRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Malaysia').getRecordTypeId();
Set<Id> sgAccountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> myAccountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id, Set<Id>> accountIdsByRecordTypeId = new Map<Id, Set<Id>> {
  sgRecordTypeId => sgAccountIdSet,
  myRecordTypeId => myAccountIdSet
};
for(Account record: newAccountList) {
  accountIdsByRecordTypeId.get(record.RecordTypeId)?.add(record.Id);
}
```

Because objects are accessed by reference, updating the value in the Map will update the related set variables.

Comment: wow `accountIdsByRecordTypeId.get(record.RecordTypeId)?.add(record.Id);` didn't know ternary operator can be used in that way o.0

Comment: @compski this is not ternary operator, but safe navigation operator https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm

Answer (score 3):

Per my understanding, you want to group account ids by their `RecordTypeId`. Consider using a `Map` for this purpose. It reduces sets where you are storing grouped elements:

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> accountsIdsByRecordTypeId = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();

for(Account accObj : newAccountList){
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    if(accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.containsKey(accObj.RecordTypeId)){
        accountIds = accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.get(accObj.RecordTypeId);
    }
    accountIds.add(accObj.Id);
    accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.put(accObj.RecordTypeId, accountIds);
}
```

Key of `accountsIdsByRecordTypeId` is a `RecordTypeId` of `Account` and value is a `Set` of `Account` ids.

---

if you have to group accounts only by specific `RecordTypeId`, create another `Set` to store ids to filter:

```
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeInfos = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();

Set<Id> accountRecortypeIdsToGroupBy = new Set<Id> {
    recordTypeInfos.get('Singapore').getRecordTypeId(),
    recordTypeInfos.get('Malaysia').getRecordTypeId();
};

Map<Id, Set<Id>> accountsIdsByRecordTypeId = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();

for(Account accObj : newAccountList){
    if(accountRecortypeIdsToGroupBy.contains(accObj.RecordTypeId)) {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        if(accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.containsKey(accObj.RecordTypeId)){
            accountIds = accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.get(accObj.RecordTypeId);
        }
        accountIds.add(accObj.Id);
        accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.put(accObj.RecordTypeId, accountIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a trigger handler that needs to split the accounts triggered by the multiple recordtypes which then needs to be fed to a separate handlers for each country. 
btw in your second code paragraph you're not calling accountRecortypeIdsToGroupBy ?

Comment: @compski there was a typo, please check updated answer `if(accountRecortypeIdsToGroupBy.contains(accObj.RecordTypeId)) {`

Comment: Thanks so much! Also for the `if(accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.containsKey(accObj.RecordTypeId)){` accountsIdsByRecordTypeId is still an empty map... still trying to understand how you able to populate the map with just 1 for loop?

Comment: line `Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();` creates empty set with accounts ids belong to one recordtype id, after that it checks if this set is already present in `Map` `if(accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.containsKey(accObj.RecordTypeId)` by account record type key, if so previosly createed empty set is assigned with valeus from the `Map` accountIds = accountsIdsByRecordTypeId.get(accObj.RecordTypeId);

Comment: The algorithm in your code is like 2x slower than just pre-populating the map with the possible keys ahead of time: `for(Account record: newAccountList) accountIdsByRecordTypeId.put(record.RecordTypeId, new Set<Id>()); for(Account record: newAccountList) accountIdsByRecordTypeId.get(record.RecordTypeId).add(record.Id);` You can eliminate all the if statements, saving you a contains and containskey

Comment: Yeah I needed to read his code for hours to understand how it really worked. But good perspectives nonetheless of the different ways it can be optimized.

Comment: @sfdcfox interesting, didn't know, that two loops are better in this case

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Yeah, you know I'm usually all about performance. I wrote something up you might want to read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984) if you're interested in performance.